# why the codewhisper always need login

Tags: amazon-codewhisperer

is it possible to login onece with amazon codewhisper? I always need to login in the visual studio code. it is annoying.

[image]

I just want to login onece and no not need to login twice anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It is a security measure to protect your session. Recent updates of the AWS Toolkit have increased the session timeout to about a month. You are able to monitor when your session is about to expiry using the `Security` tab from the AWS Builder ID page.

[image]

➡️ https://profile.aws.amazon.com